# how can I write stdout to any file on git bash?

Tags: linux, git-bash

I tryed on git bash on Windows10

```
$ php show_argv.php 1000 > out.log
```

** show_argv.php is doing just `print_r($argv[1]);`

then message appeared

```
stdout is not a tty
```

and out.log was created but content are empty.

how can I write to out.log??

Comment: How about `tee`? exmp: `php show_argv.php 1000 | tee out.log`

Comment: thankyou, but same message was appeared.

Comment: Please see if this works for you too. Use `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` then the command works fine.

Comment: it works! thank you so much! is it impossible on git-bash.exe?

Comment: please accept the answer. if it worked for you. for more detail you can read their docs.

Comment: of course I did ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this works for you too. Use `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` then the command works fine.